# Magento 2: Class Magento\Eav\Model\Attribute\Data\Checkbox does not exist

Tags: magento2

when an user try to register in frontend, magento gives me this error:

```
main.CRITICAL: Exception message: Class 
Magento\Eav\Model\Attribute\Data\Checkbox does not exist
```

I can't debug this please help.

Magento 2.2.1

Comment: hi @goplastic  these are the attribute types we have http://prntscr.com/lrzgvp

Comment: thank you @NagarajuKasa, i can't understand the connection between customer account creation and product attributes

Comment: @goplastic have you got a solution? I am getting the same issue as well

Answer (score 1):

Go to Admin,

> left navigation > Stores > Attributes > Customer

See if there are any custom attributes that are of Input type Checkbox (You will have to go into details of each attribute to check the type). I think this is the one creating the problem here. I faced this issue when migrating to **Magento 2.4.4**. The issue was resolved once I deleted this customer attribute. Not sure why it is creating problems for you in **2.2.1**. I couldn't find the model of the type

> "Magento\Eav\Model\Attribute\Data\Checkbox"

in the Magento source code in **2.4.4**. It could be this class was deprecated and removed from Magento. And custom attributes created earlier are giving issues.

Answer (score 1):

Please find the frontend_input that has value "checkbox" and change to the correct value.

```
SELECT attribute_id, frontend_input FROM eav_attribute where frontend_input = 'checkbox';
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I suspect you have a module extending Magento AbstractData to create a "checkbox" model. Here's what worked for me.

1. From MySql or whatever DB mgmt system you use, copy the contents of your eav_attribute Magento table, "select * from eav_attribute"
2. Look for an attribute using "checkbox" as a model type.  I found the culprit in the "frontend_input" column.
3. In my case, it was a Yotpo attribute.  That attribute data model ("checkbox") had been created by a Yotpo module I had disabled (SmsBump, because it would throw a fatal error if specific actions took place on the site and crash the site, and we weren't using sms messaging).  I looked in the Yotpo extension and found the file creating the "checkbox" model (yotpo/module-yotpo-messaging/Model/Attribute/Data -- "class Checkbox extends AbstractData").  Because that module was disabled, there was no "checkbox" model anymore.
4. I could not re-enable the module, so I changed the "frontend_input" type to "text" (update eav_attribute ...) since the "text" model is still a valid one in Magento.  Since we aren't using the yotpo SmsBump module, there were no new problems.